# I am new to nodejs and I'm getting reference error: io is not defined ,I can't figure it out

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, ejs

I'm new to nodejs, every time I'm running my server using  nodemon server.js , I'm getting an uncaught reference error: io is not defined at script.js:1, I have no idea what's going wrong

any help will be appreciated!!

Thats my script.js file

```js
const socket = io('/');
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid');

const myVideo = document.createElement('video');
myVideo.muted = true;

socket.emit('join-room');

let myVideoStream;

const addVideoStream = (video, stream) => {
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    video.play();
  });
  videoGrid.append(video);
};

navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    myVideoStream = stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);
  });
```

This is my server.js file

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`/${uuidv4()}`);
});

app.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
  res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room });
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('join-room', () => {
    console.log('join room');
  });
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('server is running');
});
```

that's my room.ejs file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Streamy!!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>bello</h1>
    <div id="video-grid"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't you need to import socket.io in the script.js file as you have done in the server.js file?

Comment: how to do that- like const io=require('socket.io');  I did then I got an error saying require is not defined

Comment: I guess that makes sense since script is rendered through the browser. Check this out:
https://socket.io/docs/client-installation/

Try to add const socket = io(); in your script tags in the ejs file, should register it as a global variable. Then hopefully you can reference socket in your script file

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1)**
You should start server using

```
server.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('server is running');
});
```

instead of *app.listen*, in order to require the socket.io.js file from /socket.io/socket.io.js path.

**Solution 2)**
If Can't use solution 1 change the socket.io.js path with CDN to require socket.io.js file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Streamy!!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>bello</h1>
    <div id="video-grid"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, solution 1 worked!! Thanks really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Pls ensure if socket.io.js file is accessbile in html file (you can check Network tab once under Inspect menu).

Try to replace the URL in your script tag with the below one & re-run it.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, but it worked for by replacing app.listen(portNumber) to server.listen(portNumber)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it in script like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Streamy!!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
       const socket = io();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>bello</h1>
    <div id="video-grid"></div>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and start using socket as its now a global variable

Comment: following your approach, I am getting an error: socket is already defined

Comment: @Sagarb you can use it directly as its global variable

Comment: Thanks for helping